# If f(x) = min{x, x²} for every real number x, then, find the number of points at which f(x) is not differentiable.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

If $f(x) = \min\{x, x^2\}$ for every real number $x$, then, find the number of points at which $f(x)$ is not differentiable.
Can someone kindly answer this without sketching a graph?

Comment: Consider $x>1,0<x<1,x<0$, $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Comment: Why would you *not* want to sketch a graph?

Comment: $x^2<x \Rightarrow x(x-1) <0 \Rightarrow 0<x<1$. Then you need only check $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is $x^2$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $x$ for $x<0$ and $x>1$. Therefore $f$ is differentiable at these points.

At every point that is not $x=0$ or $x=1$, your function behaves as either $x^2$ or $x$. We only need to check these two points:

$x=1$:

$lim_{x\searrow1}f'(x)=lim_{x\searrow1}1=1$

$lim_{x\nearrow1}f'(x)=lim_{x\searrow1}2x=2$

As the limits are not the same, the function $f$ is not differentiable in $x=1$

$x=0$:

$lim_{x\searrow0}f'(x)=lim_{x\searrow0}2x=0$

$lim_{x\nearrow0}f'(x)=lim_{x\searrow1}1=1$

As the limits are not the same, the function $f$ is not differentiable in $x=0$